# ¿Cómo traducir "My ideal friend would have the same hobbies as me" al español?

Tags: traducción

¿Cómo traducir esta frase al español?

> My ideal friend would have the same hobbies as me.

Yo creo que se puede decir:

> Mi amigo ideal tendría las mismas aficiones que mi.

¿Es correcto o no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Casi perfecto, salvo el final, donde debería ser "**yo**" en lugar de "**mi**", es decir:

> Mi amigo ideal tendría las mismas aficiones que yo.

Incluso podrías dejar "***hobbies***" en vez de "aficiones", pero *en cursiva*, como extranjerismo aceptado por la Real Academia:

> [***hobby***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KXu47LP)
>   Voz ingl.
>   1. m. Actividad que, como afición o pasatiempo favorito, se practica habitualmente en los ratos de ocio.

y quedaría:

> Mi amigo ideal tendría los mismos *hobbies* que yo.

Comment: Otra opción, por lo menos en México, sería *pasatiempos*.

Comment: En el **"Norti, 'i ñor"** de México, usamos preferentemente el extranjerismos "hobby", pronunciando "Jóbi" en vez de la /h/ hisseante del inglés. En rótulos o forma escrita, se usa la ortografía del inglés (**hobbies/hobby** = *jóbis jóbi*) y es rarísimo y evidencia automática de ser "fuereño" decir "pasatiempo" (seguro eres del centro) o "afición" (seguro eres del '*otro lado del charco*')